# how to add a dot recursive in file/folders permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, selinux, chown, chgrp

example of files with there permissions

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  659 Jan  4  2018 zookeeper-server-initialize
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  649 Jan  4  2018 zookeeper-server-cleanup
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  648 Jan  4  2018 zookeeper-server
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  303 Jan  4  2018 zookeeper-client
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 6822 Jan  4  2018 zkServer.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   12 Jan  4  2018 zkServer-initialize.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2840 Jan  4  2018 zkEnv.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1709 Jan  4  2018 zkCli.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2155 Jan  4  2018 zkCleanup.sh
```

in case we have just this file for example : ( without the dot )

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2155 Jan  4  2018 zkCleanup.sh
```

**Then what is the command to add this dot to the file permissions ?**

**second how to add a dot recursive**

for example on all sub folders under

```
/usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-server
```

example before

```
 pwd
/usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-server


 ls -Z
drwxr-xr-x root root ?                                bin
lrwxrwxrwx root root ?                                conf -> /etc/zookeeper/2.6.4.0-91/0
drwxr-xr-x root root ?                                doc
drwxr-xr-x root root ?                                etc
drwxr-xr-x root root ?                                lib
drwxr-xr-x root root ?                                man
drwxr-xr-x root root ?                                usr
-rw-r--r-- root root ?                                zookeeper-3.4.6.2.6.4.0-91.jar
lrwxrwxrwx root root ?                                zookeeper.jar -> zookeeper-3.4.6.2.6.4.0-91.jar
```

expected output:

```
 pwd
/usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-server

ls -Z
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       bin
lrwxrwxrwx. root root unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0   conf -> /etc/zookeeper/2.6.4.0-91/0
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       doc
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       etc
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       lib
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       man
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       usr
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       zookeeper-3.4.6.2.6.4.0-91.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       zookeeper.jar -> zookeeper-3.4.6.2.6.4.0-91.jar
```

**we try**

```
restorecon -r /usr/hdp
ls -ltr
total 12
drwxr-xr-x. 27 root root 4096 Oct 29 10:05 2.6.0.3-8
drwxr-xr-x  29 root root 4096 Nov  6 11:29 2.6.4.0-91
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Dec 31 13:01 current
```

but 2.6.4.0-91 folder with the same permissions ( include the sub folders under 2.6.4.0-91 )

```
ls -Z
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       2.6.0.3-8
drwxr-xr-x  root root ?                                2.6.4.0-91
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0   current
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trailing `.` indicates that a file has an SElinux security context. To set the default security contexts you should be able to run

```
restorecon -r /usr/hdp
```

---

The above requires that you have SELinux enabled on your system. If you do not then you will have to enable it and label the filesystem

Edit /etc/selinux/config and ensure that

```
SELINUX=enforcing # or permissive
SELINUXTYPW=targeted
```

Then run the commands

```
touch /.autorelabel
reboot
```

Comment: in case we want to remove it , so what should be the opposite way ?

Comment: we try  restorecon -r /usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-server  ( but files or folders with exactly the same permissions )   we also try restorecon -r /usr/hdp , see my update in the question

Comment: we are using OS - redhat 7.2

Comment: we also try restorecon -rF /usr/hdp ( but folder/sub folders/files with the same permissions)

Comment: for now we cant reboot the machine , other way to do it without reboot ?

Comment: Go and read the documentation on SELinux.

Comment: I see from doc that we cant set it to enable ,